# JQuery Why my array.every is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jive

I want to know why my array.every is not a function, im searching for hours but i dont understand why it is not. Can someone help me ?

```js
function controlUserInput(inputText, appLang) {
 const regex = /\$[^$]*\$/gm;
const str = $('#formulaire-preview-textarea').val();
let m;
 var array =  populateVariable(appLang);
 
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  var isEqual = match.length==array.length;
  for (i=0; i<=array.length-1;i++){
   if(displayCpt == 4 && isEqual && match.toArray().every(function(paramInMatch){
    return $.inArray(paramInMatch, array) != -1; 
   })){
    osapi.jive.core.container.sendNotification({
    "message": "Toutes les valeurs rentrées sont correctes",
    "severity": "success"
    });
   }else{
    osapi.jive.core.container.sendNotification({
    "message": "Vous n'avez pas utilisé toutes les valeurs",
    "severity": "error"
    });
   } 
  }
 })
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.toArray()` is a jQuery object method, and as your `match` is not a jQuery object, it won't work.

You could use the plain javascript `Array.from(match)`.

Comment: like that ? Array.from(match)

Comment: @WillyNguyen Correct...and check my update, as you might not need it either

Comment: apparently, when I do match.every it also returns me the error "match.every is not a function"

Comment: @WillyNguyen Then simply use `Array.from()` ... and rolled back my answer